# build php extension on windows nts mode

Tags: c++, php-extension

as new version of PHP (5.3.x or higher) on windows that compiled none thread safe mode(zendGuardLoader extension just have nts version), so I need to compile my extension with nts mode.

It success when I compiled it with mode TS, but when I want to switch on mode nts I got this error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__executor_globals_id
```

I done all setting for nts mode ok, like ZTS=0. and using php5.lib.

I use php 5.3.19 source code to compiling and vc++ 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ZTS` from your project preprocessor. `ZTS = 0` is not a good idea for compiling in nts mode.